# Undefined index: transfer_encoding

Tags: php, undefined

Ok a few weeks ago my script stopped working and today I notice I'm getting an error: [05-Mar-2017 06:31:32 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: transfer_encoding in /home2/website/public_html/maps_apps/EasyWebFetch.php on line 105.

Here is what line 105 is:

```
if ($this->_resp_headers['transfer_encoding'] == 'chunked') {
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on getting this fixed?

Here is the main code:

```
<?php
require_once '/home2/website/public_html/maps_apps/EasyWebFetch.php';

$callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : 'mymap.weatherhandler';
$station = isset($_GET['rid']) ? $_GET['rid'] : 'FWS';
$product = isset($_GET['product']) ? $_GET['product'] : 'NCR';
$nframes =  isset($_GET['frames']) ? $_GET['frames'] : 10;

if (strlen($product) != 3 || strlen($station) != 3) { exit; }

// fetch directory listing
$wf = new EasyWebFetch;
if (!$wf->get("https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/$product/$station/")) {
  print $wf->getErrorMessage();
  exit;
}
$page = $wf->getContents();
echo $page."\n\n";

$size = preg_match_all( "/href=\"({$station}[\d_]+{$product}\.gif)\"/" , $page, $match);
$files = $match[1];


if ($nframes == 'all') { $nframes = count($files); }
$nframes = min(count($files), $nframes);
$files = array_slice($files, -$nframes);

echo $callback."\n(\n{\ndirectory:\n[\n";
for ($i=0; $i < $nframes; $i++) {
  echo "\"ridge/RadarImg/$product/$station/$files[$i]\",\n";
}
echo "]\n}\n)\n;"

?>
```

and here is EasyWebFetch.php

```
<?php
/*
 * EasyWebFetch - Fetch a page by opening socket connection, no dependencies
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 * @author    Nashruddin Amin <me@nashruddin.com>
 * @copyright Nashruddin Amin 2008
 * @license   GNU General Public License 3.0
 * @package   EasyWebFetch
 * @version   1.1
 */

class EasyWebFetch 
{
    private $_request_url;
    private $_host;
    private $_path;
    private $_query;
    private $_fragment;
    private $_headers_only;
    private $_portnum       = 80;
    private $_user_agent    = "SimpleHttpClient/3.0";
    private $_req_timeout   = 30;
    private $_maxredirs     = 5;

    private $_use_proxy     = false;
    private $_proxy_host;
    private $_proxy_port;
    private $_proxy_user;
    private $_proxy_pass;

    private $_status;
    private $_resp_headers;
    private $_resp_body;

    private $_is_error;
    private $_errmsg;

    /**
     * class constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_resp_headers = array();
        $this->_resp_body    = "";
    }

    /**
     * get the requested page
     *
     * @param string  $url          URL of the requested page
     * @param boolean $headers_only true to return headers only, 
     *                              false to return headers and body
     *
     * @return  boolean true on success, false on failure
     */
    public function get($url = '', $headers_only = false)
    {
        $this->_request_url  = $url;
        $this->_headers_only = $headers_only;

        $redir = 0;

        while(($redir++) <= $this->_maxredirs) {
            $this->parseUrl($this->_request_url);

            if (($response = $this->makeRequest()) == false) {
                return(false);
            }

            /* split head and body */
            $neck = strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n");
            $head = substr($response, 0, $neck);
            $body = substr($response, $neck+2);

            /* read response headers */
            $this->_resp_headers = $this->parseHeaders($head);

            /* check for redirects */
            if ($this->getStatus() == 301 || $this->getStatus() == 302) {
                $follow = $this->_resp_headers['location'];
                $this->_request_url = $this->setFullPath($follow, $this->_request_url);
                continue;
            } else {
                /* no redirects, start reading response body */
                break;
            }
        }

        /* read the body part */
        if ($this->_resp_headers['transfer_encoding'] == 'chunked') {
            $this->_resp_body = $this->joinChunks($body);
        } else {
            $this->_resp_body = $body;
        }

        return(true);
    }

    /**
     * build HTTP header and perform HTTP request
     *
     * @return  mixed   HTTP response on success, false on failure
     */
    private function makeRequest()
    {
        $method     = ($this->_headers_only == true) ? "HEAD" : "GET";
        $proxy_auth = base64_encode("$this->_proxy_user:$this->_proxy_pass");
        $response   = "";

        if ($this->_use_proxy) {
            $headers = "$method $this->_request_url HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                     . "Host: $this->_host\r\n"
                     . "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $proxy_auth\r\n"
                     . "User-Agent: $this->_user_agent\r\n"
                     . "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            $fp = fsockopen($this->_proxy_host, $this->_proxy_port, $errno, $errmsg, $this->_req_timeout);
        } else {
            $headers = "$method $this->_path$this->_query$this->_fragment HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                     . "Host: $this->_host\r\n"
                     . "User-Agent: $this->_user_agent\r\n"
                     . "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            $fp = fsockopen($this->_host, $this->_portnum, $errno, $errmsg, $this->_req_timeout);
        }       

        if (!$fp) {
            $this->_is_error = true;
            $this->_errmsg   = "Unknown error";
            return(false);
        }       
        fwrite($fp, $headers);

        while(!feof($fp)) {
            $response .= fgets($fp, 4096);
        }       
        fclose($fp);

        return($response);
    }

    /**
     * parse the requested URL to its host, path, query and fragment
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function parseUrl($url)
    {
        $this->_host     = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $this->_path     = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $this->_query    = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        $this->_fragment = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);

        if (empty($this->_path)) {
            $this->_path = '/';
        }
    }

    /**
     * get the full path of the page to redirect. if the requested page is
     * http://www.example.com and it redirects to redirpage.html, then the
     * new request is http://www.example.com/redirpage.html
     *
     * @param string $loc           new location from the HTTP response headers
     * @param string $parent_url    the parent's URL
     *
     * @return string  full path of the page to redirect
     */
    private function setFullPath($loc, $parent_url)
    {
        $parent_url = preg_replace("/\/[^\/]*$/", "", $parent_url);

        if (strpos($loc, 'http://') !== false) {
            return($loc);
        }       
        if (strpos($loc, '../') === false) {
            return("$parent_url/$loc");
        }

        while (strpos($loc, '../') !== false) {
            $loc        = preg_replace("/^\.\.\//", "", $loc);
            $parent_url = preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+$/", "", $parent_url);
        }

        return("$parent_url/$loc"); 
    }

    /**
     * parse HTTP response headers to array
     *
     * @param string $string HTTP response headers
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    private function parseHeaders($string)
    {
        $string  = trim($string);
        $headers = array();

        $lines = explode("\r\n", $string);

        $headers['http_status'] = $lines[0];

        /* read HTTP _status in first line */
        preg_match('/HTTP\/(\\d\\.\\d)\\s*(\\d+)\\s*(.*)/', $lines[0], $m);
        $this->_status = $m[2];

        array_splice($lines, 0, 1); /* remove first line */

        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            list($key, $val) = explode(': ', $line);

            $key = str_replace("-", "_", $key);
            $key = strtolower($key);
            $val = trim($val);

            $headers[$key] = $val;  
        }
        return($headers);
    }

    /**
     * join parts of the HTTP response body with chunked transfer-encoding
     *
     * @param string $chunks HTTP response body
     * 
     * @return string full body
     */
    private function joinChunks($chunks)
    {
        preg_match("/\r\n([0-9a-z]+)(;?.*)\r\n/", $chunks, $match);
        $size = hexdec($match[1]);

        $body = "";

        while($size > 0) {  
            /* remove line with chunk size */
            $chunks = preg_replace("/\r\n.+\r\n/m", "", $chunks, 1); 

            $part   = substr($chunks, 0, $size);
            $chunks = substr($chunks, $size);

            $body .= $part;

            /* get next chunk size */
            preg_match("/\r\n([0-9a-z]+)(;?.*)\r\n/", $chunks, $match);
            $size = hexdec($match[1]);
        }   
        return($body);
    }

    /**
     * set the requested URL
     *
     * @param string $url URL of the requested page
     */
    public function setRequestUrl($url)
    {
        $this->_request_url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * set to return headers only
     *
     * @param boolean $headers_only true to return headers only,
     *                              false to return headers and body
     */
    public function returnHeadersOnly($headers_only)
    {
        $this->_headers_only = $headers_only;
    }

    /**
     * set proxy host and port
     *
     * @param string $hostport proxy host and proxy port in format proxy_host:proxy_port
     */
    public function setProxyHost($hostport)
    {
        list($this->_proxy_host, $this->_proxy_port) = explode(':', $hostport);
        $this->_use_proxy = true;
    }

    /**
     * set proxy user and password
     *
     * @param string $userpass proxy user and password in format proxy_user:proxy_password
     */
    public function setProxyUser($userpass)
    {
        list($this->_proxy_user, $this->_proxy_pass) = explode(':', $userpass);
    }

    /**
     * get the HTTP response status (200, 404, etc)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return($this->_status);
    }

    /**
     * get the requested URL
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRequestUrl()
    {
        return($this->_request_url);
    }

    /**
     * set maximum redirects
     *
     * @param int $maxredirs
     */
    public function setMaxRedirs($maxredirs)
    {
        $this->_maxredirs = $maxredirs;
    }

    /**
     * get HTTP response headers
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getHeaders()
    {
        return($this->_resp_headers);
    }

    /**
     * get the HTTP response body, usually in HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContents()
    {
        return($this->_resp_body);
        echo $this->_resp_body;
    }

    /**
     * get error message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getErrorMessage()
    {
        return($this->_errmsg);
    }

    /**
     * print debug information
     */
    private function debug($text)
    {
        print "$text\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The array `_resp_headers` doesn't have any element with key `transfer_encoding`.

To fix the notice, you should check if the array has the key `transfer_encoding`:

```
if (array_key_exists('transfer_encoding', $this->_resp_headers) && $this->_resp_headers['transfer_encoding'] == 'chunked') {
```

But I can't tell you why the key is not set and why the script has stopped working if you don't show more code.

Comment: When you call https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/$product/$station/ the http response doesn't contain the header transfer_encoding

Comment: a few weeks ago, everything is working. Nothing changed on my server.

Comment: @BrandonHolland radar.weather.gov is your server?

Answer (score 0):

difficult to answer with such a small sample of code but you can check for the index's existence before

```
if (isset($this->_resp_headers['transfer_encoding']) && 
    $this->_resp_headers['transfer_encoding'] == 'chunked') {
```